# Cross-browser Numeric Spinner / Stepper for Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a numeric spinner which integrates with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3, using the HTML5 `input type="number"`

[image: stepper]

```
<input type="number" id="income" name="income" value="10">
```

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) at the time of this writing, only Chrome renders this element as I wish. Probably Firefox will do this soon and in no more than 5 to 10 years from now, IE will also come up with a solution.

I've tested a couple of them, but all were 3+ years old, rely on jQuery UI and do not exactly integrate properly with Bootstrap.

**Meanwhile I was just curious if there are any jQuery libraries / or other solution that render the input as in the screenshot.**

Comment: The problem with this kind of rendering is that it is very hard to use  on small devices. That's why I made [Bootstrap TouchSpin](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/), which is easier to handle on touch devices and is cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recently I came across the [Fuel UX](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/) library which also includes a [spinner](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#spinner).

[image: Spinner Fuel UX]

Answer (score 9):

What about this [bootstrap-spinedit](http://geersch.github.io/bootstrap-spinedit/)?
It's rather old but still working as expected these days.

<s>**NOTE**: demos do not work cause they reference non existing scripts.</s>

You can see how it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/93V8v/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="aSpinEdit" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.aSpinEdit').spinedit({
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 50,
    step: 1
});
```

Comment: So far the best solution I've tested. Unfortunately the project itself does not seem to be very popular or active.

Comment: Yes, I know but it seems the author is still working and fixing it.

Comment: doesnt seems to work in b4

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is one of those that you tested, but it is part of the official jQuery UI set of widgets:

http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already checked the Spinner from jQuery UI, but it does not integrate nicely with what I have.